# Django problematic view

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-generic-views

I have this Django generic view:

```
def post_list(request, page=0, paginate_by=1, **kwargs):
page_size = getattr(settings,'BLOG_PAGESIZE', paginate_by)
return list_detail.object_list(
    request,
    queryset=Post.objects.published(),
    paginate_by=page_size,
    page=page,
    **kwargs
)
post_list.__doc__ = list_detail.object_list.__doc__
```

and I want to send it the current year to use it in the template. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the year in via [`extra_context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/?from=olddocs#date-based-generic-views), for the current year:

```
from datetime import datetime
year = datetime.now().year
```

Answer (score 0):

You core problem is using generic views - http://stdout.be/2010/05/25/generic-views-suck/

```
def post_list(request, page=0, paginate_by=1, **kwargs):
    page_size = getattr(settings,'BLOG_PAGESIZE', paginate_by)
    queryset = Post.objects.published()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset, page_size) 
    objects = paginator.page(page)

    #This stuff is only necessary if you aren't trapping page in the URL conf
    #page = request.GET.get('page')
    #try:
    #    objects = paginator.page(page)
    #except PageNotAnInteger:
    #    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    #    objects = paginator.page(1)
    #except EmptyPage:
    #    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    #    objects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', {"objects": objects, "year": datetime.now().year}, context=RequestContext(request))
```

Compared to the original, which code would you rather maintain or extend?